# Using two keyboards, different layouts

Tags: keyboard

I use two keyboards on the mac, the default mac keyboard and a windows default (Microsoft wireless desktop).

I use the **microsoft keyboard one for the left hand**, and the **mac keyboard for the right hand**.

The problem is that when I press a key on microsoft keyboard like <kbd>shift</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>esc</kbd>, and another key on the mac it **doesn't get detected as a combination**. I have to press the full combination on the same keyboard.

**Is it possible to override this?**

I'm used to typing <kbd>⇧</kbd> (Keyboard A) and <kbd>char</kbd> (Keyboard B) in order to get an upper case char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac won't do key combinations across keyboards, even with an Apple external and a MacBook Pro internal.

I know of no utility to allow this, either.